# How can I interpret the time with less code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Moved to stackexchange:
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/135436/how-can-i-interpret-the-time-with-less-code

I really don't like sticking many if's together, I think it looks like a child stacking...but if anyone knows how to do the same thing I'm doing with this code  but with less lines, it would be great.

```
if(json.Data.length>0){
                for(var i=0;i<=json.Data.length-1;i++)
                { 
                    s += '<tr><td>' + data[i].data1+ '</td>';
                    s += '<td>'+ data[i].data2+ '</td>';
                    if(data[i].data3== null) {
                        s += '<td>N / A</td>' +
                            '<td>Has not logged in.</td>';
                    }
                    else {
                        s += '<td>' + moment(data[i].data3).format('DD MMM YYYY hh:mm A') + '</td>';

                        var time = data[i].data4;
                        var summary = '<td>' + time + ' minutes since last login.</td></tr>';
                        if(time >= 60) {
                            var hour= tiempo / 60;
                            summary = '<td>' + Math.floor(hora) + ' hours since last login.</td></tr>';
                            if(hour>= 24) {
                                var day = hour/ 24;
                                summary= '<td>' + Math.floor(day) + ' days since last login.</td></tr>';
                                if(dia >= 7) {
                                    var week= day / 7;
                                    summary = '<td>' + Math.floor(week) + ' weeks since last login.</td></tr>';
                                    if(week >= 4) {
                                        var month = week / 4;
                                        summary = '<td>' + Math.floor(mes) + ' months since last login.</td></tr>';
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            s += summary;
                        } else {
                            s += summary;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            $('#bodytable').empty().append(s);
```

What really matters here is from line

```
var time = data[i].data4;
```

and on.

For some context: `data[i].data4` is from a column that is an operation of

`DATEDIFF(mi, Column3, getdate())`.

As you can see, the returned results would be in minutes and from then on I start checking how many hours, days, and so on from that and I would even love to add between each line an (if it's greater than 1) so I can change the wording to singular instead of plural but I think that's too many lines just for a decision of whether to simply write 'minute' instead of 'minutes'.

Comment: If you can create a demo of this working. IE ( codepen, jsfiddle, plunker). This might be better asked at Code Review. http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask Assuming this is working code that you want to optimize.

Comment: Since you are using `moment` Why not use moment's display option? http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/from/

Comment: Alright, thanks for letting me know. I'll move it there.

Comment: @Alan Because even if I did use it, I would still have to create an if within another if just to validate if (minutes >= minutesIn24Hours) { moment.duration(minutes, "hours").humanize()
}
And so on for cases such as days, weeks, and months

Comment: You might try using a Switch (Case) statement, rather than nesting all the IFs.  It would be cleaner, at least.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as it is better suited for [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @dreami Sorry I had updated my comment to suggest using "display" functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% certain about your JSON object, but you can use [momentjs#fromNow](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/fromnow/) to get the relative time string.

Which super simplifies the code.

```
if(json.Data.length>0){
    for(var i=0;i<=json.Data.length-1;i++) { 
        s += '<tr><td>' + data[i].data1+ '</td>';
        s += '<td>'+ data[i].data2+ '</td>';
        if(data[i].data3== null) {
            s += '<td>N / A</td>' +
                '<td>Has not logged in.</td>';
        }
        else {
            s += '<td>' + moment(data[i].data3).format('DD MMM YYYY hh:mm A') + '</td>';
            // not 100% sure what this value is.
            s += '<td>last login ' + moment(data[i].data4).fromNow() +'</td>'
            // will output:
            // last login 15 seconds ago
            // last login 4 years ago
            // last login 3 weeks ago
        }
    }
}
$('#bodytable').empty().append(s);
```

If you need the exact formatted strings, you can update them in [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/relative-time/).

```
moment.updateLocale('en', {
    relativeTime : {
        past:   "%s"
    }
});

// then it would look like:
s += '<td>' + moment(data[i].data4).fromNow() +' since last login</td>';
// 5 minutes since last login
// a hour since last login
// 187 years since last login
```